how to change the section* title with ctexart?
I was trying to practice the ctexset option in ctex package, but I found that the title of the toc will share the style with that inside the ctexset, just as below:
\documentclass[12pt]{ctexart}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{我是目录我是目录}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\ctexset{
    section = {
        format=\Huge\bfseries\linespread{1.5}\selectfont\centering,
        titleformat=\color{orange}\songti,
        name={第,部分},
        number=\chinese{section},
        numberformat=\color{magenta},
        aftername={ : },
        aftertitle={\quad\ding{72}\ding{72}\ding{72}\par}
    },
    subsection = {
        format=\linespread{1.5}\selectfont,
        name={\S},
        numberformat=\color{blue}\zihao{3}\itshape,
        titleformat=\kaishu\color{violet}\zihao{4}\ttfamily,
        aftername={\quad},
        aftertitle={\hskip4pt(surprise here!)}
    },
    subsubsection = {
        indent=4\ccwd,
        format=\yahei\large,
        number={\Roman{section}--\roman{subsection}--\arabic{subsubsection}},
        aftertitle={\hskip4pt\ding{52}}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{这是第一个章节}
\subsection{第一个子章节}
\subsection{第二个子章节}
\subsubsection{第一个可爱的subsubsection}
\subsubsection{第二个可爱的subsubsection}
\subsubsection{第三个可爱的subsubsection}
\subsection{第三个子章节}
\section{这是第二个章节}
\subsection{第一个子章节}
\subsection{第二个子章节}
\subsection{第三个子章节}
\end{document}

Compiling with the XeLaTeX engine, I found that I want to remove the three stars after the title only in the toc and center the title of contents, but I found it useless to just rendefine the macro \contensname. As shown below....

My Question is how to change the style of the title of the TOC locally, for the purpose of learning the usage of package titletoc and tocloft, could I succeeded in modifying that just with titletoc or just tocloft. Another curiosity is the relation between the package titletoc and tocloft, are they substitudes? or overlap on some usage? or may cause some conflicts?

For your first question:

I want to remove the three stars after the title only in the toc

Just create a local group and remove the global value of aftertitle in this group:
\begingroup
\ctexset{section = {aftertitle={}}}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

or in expl3 fashion
\ExplSyntaxOn
\group_begin:
\ctex_set:nn { section } { aftertitle = {} }
\tableofcontents
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff



It is actually a good idea of solution, but I think the article.cls define the \tableofcontents with \section* although guarantee the consisitency of the section part in document shared the same style, but it actually cause the problem just like above... A little bit not friendly of reset the style of the title in ToC....

For the second problem. I fould that in functions, the tocloft is more flexible than the titletoc.

There is another more flexible and complicated package: etoc.

I will spare time on that. Thanks!
